# Arduino pulseIn returns weird values

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to connect my arduino board to my RC receiver. I have the receiver powered using a pretty standard 4xAA pack, and I have one channel of the receiver connected to port 7 on the arduino (I've tried several different pins for this). The code below just returns numbers in the range of 8000 (sometimes 9000 and sometimes 7000), but this doesn't change when I apply controls from the transmitter to the channel. What's weirder is that the numbers return even when the wire to port 7 is unplugged from the receiver (but still attached to the arduino). Does this make sense? Any thoughts?

```
int pin = 7;
unsigned long duration;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(pin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Pour a bowl of Serial
}

void loop()
{
  duration = pulseIn(pin, LOW);
  Serial.print("Channel 1:"); // Print the value of 
  Serial.println(duration);        // each channel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you want to measure the pulse width of the signal your R/C receiver is outputting? To do this, you need to use interrupts. The way I've done this is as follows:

```
volatile int16_t pwm = 0; //pwm value
volatile int16_t trig = 0; //timer value
#define pin 7 //pin the interrupt is attached to

void intHandler() //function to call on interrupt
{
    if(digitalRead(pin)) //if the pin is HIGH, note the time
  {
    trig = micros();
  }
  else
  {
    pwm = micros()-trig; //if it is low, end the time
  }
}

void setup(){
  pinMode(pin, INPUT); //set the pin to input
  attachInterrupt(pin,intHandler,CHANGE); //attach the interrupt function "intHandler" to "pin" whenever the state changes
  Serial.begin(9600); //begin serial comms
}

void loop()
{

  Serial.print("PWM = ");   
  Serial.println(pwm);
}
```

Note that this probably only works on the Arduino Due, which has extended interrupt handling capability. However, this should give you the general idea of how to do it. The interrupt capability is only available on [certain pins](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt), and that may be why the pulseIn function isn't working for you.

Comment: If this worked out for you, I'd appreciate marking it as the answer. If not, let's see if we can figure it out.

Comment: Hi achase90, your solution works, however the real issue was caused by improper ground on my part. That was causing the weird numbers, not the code itself. I up voted you because your solution would work in the long run, but would not solve the immediate problem :)